# Comment Count API Facebook Restfb Java

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb, facebook-java-api, facebook4j

I've been programming a lot with restfb, but I'm not able to do a counting of comments, only the comments without the answers, the image can better illustrate.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n095v.png)

[Example post comment facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n095v.png)

My code

```
Post post = clienteFacebook.fetchObject(idPostagem,
                Post.class,
                Parameter.with("fields", "comments.limit(0).summary(true)"), 
                Parameter.with("filter", "toplevel"));

        System.out.println("Comments count: " + post.getCommentsCount());
```

[Out code comments count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3LY0.png)

But I need to get only actual comments from the publication, in this example 57 comments.

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/comments I have some references of filter - toplevel but without success.

I also tested with Comment instead of Post but without success.

How can I get 57 posts in a post?

Comment: `total_count` in combination with `filter=toplevel` should get you the count of only those, according to documentation. If it shows this behavior reproducible over several different posts, then file a bug report maybe. (The docs say, _“Note: total_count can be greater than or equal to the actual number of comments returned due to comment privacy or deletion.”_ - but I don’t think that should explain that kind of discrepancy.)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
Post post = clienteFacebook.fetchObject(idPostagem,
      Post.class,Parameter.with("fields", "comments.limit(0).summary(1).filter(toplevel)"));

System.out.println("Comments count: " + post.getCommentsCount());
```

As you can see the filter is part of the fields parameter. But the strange thing is, `toplevel` is the default filter if no filter is provided. So maybe it is something different.

Maybe you can get in touch with us (RestFB Team) directly, so we can help a bit more in depth ;)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I tested the example and gave the same result. I'll talk to you.